# Windows 7 cmd is not sorting my files in intuitive mode

Tags: sorting, windows-7, cmd, dir

How can I solve this?

I already try change the register and it didnt work.

My computer doesnt have `gpedit.msc` either.

[image: cmd dir]

Comment: If by *intuitive mode* you mean ordering by numeric value, try **dir /od** or set **DIRCMD=/ODG** in your environment permanently. This should work if your Dataanalyser creates images chronologically by numeric name.

Comment: What made you think the `dir` command was capable of sorting files numerically?  As far as I know, it isn't.

Comment: Shall we guess what you believe is intuitive mode?

Comment: Well, thank you for all your comments. I could not change this. But Solve my problem in another way. 

I was creating some gif animations using ImageMagick and it keep adding the images in this order. So I thought changing this, I could fix the ImageMagick gifs.